# Retrieving ParameterValuePtr from SQLHSTMT

Tags: odbc

After I call SQLBindParameter(), is there a way to get back my ParameterValuePtr from the statement object?

I'd like to use dynamically allocated memory for my parameter and after the DB call is done, I'd need to free it. If I could retrieve my pointer (which obviously the statement object holds internally) that would save me from dragging the pointer around in my application.

Thanks!

Comment: While not exactly off-topic here, this is more of a programmer-orientated question. You might prefer to delete it here and ask on [SO] instead?